# How to make multilines of text fade in and up and a different rate per line?

Tags: html, css

Notice on on the following animated gif, the text fades in and up... also notice how that each line of text has a slight delay to the line above...

How can this effect be done with CSS?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you do it:

```css
/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes slideInFromBottomMulti {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: translateY(50px); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50px); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: translateY(50px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    -ms-transform: translateY(0); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    -ms-transform: translateY(0); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: translateY(0); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes slideInFromBottomMulti {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: translateY(50px); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50px); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: translateY(50px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    -ms-transform: translateY(0); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80% {
    -ms-transform: translateY(0); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: translateY(0); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

#showcase-multi p{
  margin: 5px 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

#showcase-multi{
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 1.7rem;
  background-color: #CC0000;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
}
#showcase-multi #first-row{
  -webkit-animation: slideInFromBottomMulti 2s ease-out 0s infinite; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation: slideInFromBottomMulti 2s ease-out 0s infinite;
}
#showcase-multi #second-row{
  -webkit-animation: slideInFromBottomMulti 2s ease-out 0.15s infinite; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation: slideInFromBottomMulti 2s ease-out 0.15s infinite;
}
#showcase-multi #third-row{
  -webkit-animation: slideInFromBottomMulti 2s ease-out 0.3s infinite; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation: slideInFromBottomMulti 2s ease-out 0.3s infinite;
}
```

```html
    <div id="showcase-multi">
      <p id="first-row">First row</p>
      <p id="second-row">Second row</p>
      <p id="third-row">Third row</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is nice, thank you... but notice how the text flashes badly when it first appears?

Comment: @AnnaSm you can adjust speed to get the result that you like

Comment: @AnnaSm try it now it should be netter.